# Compare two Firestore Timestamps in Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing update function in Firestore and I want to compare two `Timestamp`. I've tried multiple things but not working. Can you point me correct way of comparing two `Timestamp` in firestore.

```
exports.updateFunction = functions.firestore
    .document('xyz/{xyzId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
        var updatedXYZ = change.after.data();
        var oldXYZ = change.before.data();

        var newTimestamp = updatedXYZ.timing;
        var oldTimestamp = oldXYZ.timing;

        // I've tried following things but not working

        var result = newTimestamp === oldTimestamp; // not working
        var result = new Date(newTimestamp) - new Date(oldTimestamp); // not working

        return true;
    });
```

I want to check two Timestamp is same or not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consult the API docs for Firestore's [Timestamp object.](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.15.x/Timestamp)  Timestamp has a method called [isEqual()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.15.x/Timestamp#isEqual) that will compare two timestamps.

```
var result = newTimestamp.isEqual(oldTimestamp);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add this line

```
admin.firestore().settings( { timestampsInSnapshots: true })
```

in your index.js file.

After adding this line cloud function will read your timestamp field as **Timestamp** Datatype. Now you can compare two timestamps using

```
var result = newTimestamp.isEqual(oldTimestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//I assume you have yourTimestampInMilliseconds
const currentTimestamp = Date.now();

console.log("(currentTimestamp <= yourTimestampInMilliseconds)= "+ (currentTimestamp <= yourTimestampInMilliseconds));
console.log("(currentTimestamp > yourTimestampInMilliseconds)= "+ (currentTimestamp > yourTimestampInMilliseconds));
```